# how to initialize a variable to zero in nasm and change it later on in nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm

What I'm trying to do is initialize a result variable to zero so that I can add to it with some value later in the program. But I'm worried about the equ constant, does it compute for the length of the initialized value only? If yes, how can I make a *result* variable zero so I can perform operations and add it later in *result* in another way than this?

```
    section .data
    result db '0'
    length equ $-result
```

Comment: The `equ` only applies to `length` setting it to the size of `result`. `result` itself is a single byte with value zero, that you are free to change at runtime.

Comment: @Jester Thanks. I'm not sure why but when I tried this,I got  the *beroset-p-637-invalid effective address* error. Have you experienced this perhaps?

Comment: Maybe you should have put that error and the code you used into the question? `mov byte [result], '1'` or something like that should work.

Comment: @Jester '&' was a typo, it should be '$' and the error's gone. Oops